# firebase.database() Date is not submitted

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to create a record in the firebase real-time database from an AngularJS web application.

**Code**

```
firebase.database().ref("XYZ").push({
      name: 'name',
      contentType: 'video/mp4',
      videoUrl:downloadURL,
      createdDate: new Date(),
      uploadedBy: 'admin@xyz.com'
})
```

**Problem**

Record created successfully but `createdDate` field will not added in database. what is the issue?

Comment: Yes thanks @DevidFarinelli :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are trying to push a [`Date object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead of a timestamp/string. You should use:

- `Date()` to get a string like: `Thu Jun 30 2016 09:40:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)`
- `new Date().getTime()` or `Date.now()` to get a timestamp like `461467272336700`

**If you are looking for a nicer solution** you should let Firebase set that value with its current date using [`firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue)